# Создание токена востановления пароля ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет. Пытаюсь прикрутить пример с метанита https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/16.6.php 
По востановлению пароля.

На методе

```
var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

Ошибка

No IUserTokenProvider named 'Default' is registered.

Всюду в инете старая реализация метода где принимается user.Id. Теперь этот метод принимает полноценного юзера,

Вот полный код метода

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null/* || !(await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))*/)
            {
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
            MailSend emailService = new MailSend();
            await emailService.SendResetPassword(model.Email, 
                $"Для відновлення паролю перейдіть за посиланням: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Все что можно перепробывал. Почему там ексепшен? Юзера он находит без проблем!

Comment: схожая ошибка [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069392/asp-net-identity-cant-register-usertokenprovider)

Comment: Aleksey Muratov  Спасибо, помогло, я б никогда не додумался, там надо в классе стартап добавить метод  .AddDefaultTokenProviders()   На метаните этот момент упущен..перерывал много раз, подобного не встречал...

Comment: я тоже об этом думал. Рад что помогло!